# Reading Properties of all Files existing in one of the folders on Application Server and print on a JSP

Tags: file, jboss, struts

I have to read the Name and Creation Date/Last Modified Date of all the files that may exist on `/product/xyz folder`, existing on `JBoss Application Server` and print the same on JSP.

This folder is being loaded with the fresh files when server is booted. The framework used is `Struts 1.2`.

Any hints or examples around how to read these information and print on JSP? Thanks!

**EDIT :**

I understand that it is much easy to read the files from a folder which might be part of my workspace folder. But, this is a different scenario.

Here, the JSP file will be deployed on JBoss application server, in some ABC folder, as part of some EARs. On the same application server, there is some other XYZ location, which will be loaded with the fresh files, when server is booted. I want to read the files existing in that XYZ folder. I Hope the scenario is more clear now.

Comment: How does the location of the files matter?

Comment: @DaveNewton - I have to read the files from a folder which is not part of my Workspace i.e. the folder would not be part of the EAR which I am deploying. So when I am using `File path = new File("/product/xyz");` `File files[] = path.listFiles();`, it is not able to find the path mentioned.

Comment: Does the directory exist? Shouldn't be an issue.

Comment: @DaveNewton Yeah.. It does exist!

Comment: Does the JBoss user have access to the directory?

Comment: @DaveNewton - Permission to the folder was the only problem there. It's working fine for me now! :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code doesn't change whether I try to access the files from my Work Space folders (Rather, which are to be part of EARs) or I may access from the Server File System (Outside the EARs).

The issue could be there in Path Mentioned or the Permission (Read/Write) to the Folder from which the files are being read.